# IOS Swift UICollectionView,I want a different tag for every cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, uicollectionview

You know at `tableviews` you can set up an array and than put every element of the array as a text for the `row` For example:

I have a `tableView`.

An `array : items = ["hello","world","yes"]`

And in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function you just say: `cell.text = items[indexPath.row]...`This is a short example.

So now is the problem.I have a collection view,which has two columns(`numberOfItemsInSection` function returns this),and I have 33 rows(`numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` function returns this)....this means I have `66(2x33)` cells.I want for each cell to display another text in it,so I made an array "items" of Strings which has 66 elements.From position 0 to position 65...how can I do like in the example at the tableview,just write `cell.text = items[I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO WRITE HERE]...`this is my problem.I don't know how to identify each cell,to be different from each other.
I would specify that if I would write: `cell.text = items[indexPath.row]` it would put in the first column the first item of the array,in the second column the second item of the array and thats all. I also tried with `indexPath.item` but it does the same like `indexPath.row`.

Thank you for help! It would help me a lot!

Comment: How is your data arranged? Do you have an array of arrays or an array of dictionaries to populate your collection view?

Answer (score 0):

Just organise your items into the two arrays,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.items1 = ["hello", "word"]
    self.items2 = ["hello2", "word2"]
    self.itemsSections = [items1, items2]
}
```

I attach example for UITableView, but you can easy adopt it to UICollectionView datasource protocol
Then use itemsSections in table datasource:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return itemsSections.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section = itemsSections[section]
    return section.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let section = itemsSections[indexPath.section]
    cell.text = section[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```